# Jenkins build 'cannot find current revision' at GitHub

Tags: git, github, jenkins, git-submodules

I have a (private) project at GitHub which has a submodule.  When I invoke the ant build at the command line in Terminal (OSX), the build is fine.  But when the same `build.xml` is invoked via Jenkins the main project is OK, but for the submodule I get:

> /usr/local/git/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive returned
>   status code 1: stdout:  stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision Unable
>   to find current revision in submodule path 'mysubmodule'

The same git command on the command line in Terminal returns

> Submodule path 'mysubmodule': checked out
>   'e9a04b127f40ba4c11f45718761a0e7965638394'

I am a relative beginner with both Jenkins and GitHub and I'm frankly not sure where to go with this.  I have searched the web, but found very little and not apparently relevant content about this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message on my windows slave and I've figured out that I simply have no permissions to read protected repository. Adding private keys to `Git\.ssh` directory fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git submodule update --remote --recursive` to update your submodules.