Unable to find current revision in submodule path
I'm trying for last two days to resolve this error and tried all these below commands that i found on internet but nothing working for me.
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule sync
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
rm -rf JSONedit
git submodule update --init --recursive

But I'm always ending up with this below error
fatal: Unable to find current revision in submodule path "path to my submodule"

Can anyone please help me?
PS: I have been went through a lot of threads on stackover flow but nothing worked.

Can you show what you tried that didn't work? Please [edit] the question and add code blocks with examples.

I tried the above commands that i mentioned. I'm not allowed to show any code blocks. It's basically I cloned a repo and then i run this command "git submodule update --init --recursive" to get submodules. But its failing with the above mentioned error.

I suspect this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59732186/7976758 The submodule is pinned to a branch or a commit that don't exist anymore in the remote repository. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40987947/7976758 git pull --recurse-submodules or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40413471/7976758 git submodule update --remote --recursive Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+Unable+to+find+current+revision+in+submodule+path

I tried the above commands as well, the first one with git pull fetch changes but there are a lot of unresolve references. That means it's getting all the changes and the second command gives the same error i mentioned in my question.

So, I manage to resolve this issue. The problem was with access permission. Submodule HEAD was referring to nonexistent branch. And because of my access permission I was not able to checkout to a commit. After getting permissions, Everything went well. Answer might be helpful for others having same trouble.
